# Is there a unicode-ready substitute I can use for urllib.quote and urllib.unquote in Python 2.6.5?

Tags: python, unicode, urllib

Python's `urllib.quote` and `urllib.unquote` do not handle Unicode correctly in Python 2.6.5. This is what happens:

```
In [5]: print urllib.unquote(urllib.quote(u'Cataño'))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/kkinder/<ipython console> in <module>()

/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib.pyc in quote(s, safe)
   1222             safe_map[c] = (c in safe) and c or ('%%%02X' % i)
   1223         _safemaps[cachekey] = safe_map
-> 1224     res = map(safe_map.__getitem__, s)
   1225     return ''.join(res)
   1226 

KeyError: u'\xc3'
```

Encoding the value to UTF8 also does not work:

```
In [6]: print urllib.unquote(urllib.quote(u'Cataño'.encode('utf8')))
CataÃ±o
```

It's recognized as a bug and [there is a fix](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/1e21d94e05f4/), but not for my version of Python.

What I'd like is something similar to urllib.quote/urllib.unquote, but handles unicode variables correctly, such that this code would work:

```
decode_url(encode_url(u'Cataño')) == u'Cataño'
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Luckily, it seems the OP has somehow got confused: as the traceback shows, this is really 2.6.

Comment: I don't know what's happening on your end, but I pasted your quote/unquote example verbatim into my interpreter python2.6, and it correctly printed Cataño.

Comment: Ah, nm, bobince already answered that below.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> Python's urllib.quote and urllib.unquote do not handle Unicode correctly

`urllib` does not handle Unicode at all. URLs don't contain non-ASCII characters, by definition. When you're dealing with `urllib` you should use only byte strings. If you want those to represent Unicode characters you will have to encode and decode them manually.

[IRIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier) can contain non-ASCII characters, encoding them as UTF-8 sequences, but Python doesn't, at this point, have an `irilib`.

> Encoding the value to UTF8 also does not work:

```
In [6]: print urllib.unquote(urllib.quote(u'Cataño'.encode('utf8')))
CataÃ±o
```

Ah, well now you're typing Unicode into a console, and doing `print`-Unicode to the console. This is generally unreliable, especially in Windows and in your case [with the IPython console](http://projects.scipy.org/ipython/ipython/ticket/239).

Type it out the long way with backslash sequences and you can more easily see that the `urllib` bit does actually work:

```
>>> u'Cata\u00F1o'.encode('utf-8')
'Cata\xC3\xB1o'
>>> urllib.quote(_)
'Cata%C3%B1o'

>>> urllib.unquote(_)
'Cata\xC3\xB1o'
>>> _.decode('utf-8')
u'Cata\xF1o'
```

Comment: Actually the problem was that I never decoded the URL when I was testing with UTF8. Simple mistake.

Answer (score 5):

"""Encoding the value to UTF8 also does not work""" ... the result of your code is a `str` object which at a guess appears to be the input encoded in UTF-8. You need to decode it or define "does not work" -- what *do* you expect?

Note: So that we don't need to guess the encoding of your terminal and the type of your data, use `print repr(whatever)` instead of `print whatever`.

```
>>> # Python 2.6.6
... from urllib import quote, unquote
>>> s = u"Cata\xf1o"
>>> q = quote(s.encode('utf8'))
>>> u = unquote(q).decode('utf8')
>>> for x in (s, q, u):
...     print repr(x)
...
u'Cata\xf1o'
'Cata%C3%B1o'
u'Cata\xf1o'
>>>
```

For comparison:

```
>>> # Python 3.2
... from urllib.parse import quote, unquote
>>> s = "Cata\xf1o"
>>> q = quote(s)
>>> u = unquote(q)
>>> for x in (s, q, u):
...     print(ascii(x))
...
'Cata\xf1o'
'Cata%C3%B1o'
'Cata\xf1o'
>>>
```

Comment: Very simply, I expect the result from unqoute to be what I sent to quote(). I figured out that urllib is basically expecting a latin1 encoding.

Comment: @Ken: I would expect that `latin1` is accidental rather than an expectation. In any case, `latin` won't handle your problem in general. You should also expect that the result of `quote()` will give the "right" answer -- hence my comparison with Python 3.2. Python 2.6.6 quote using `latin1` instead of `utf8` produces `'Cata%F1o'`

Comment: This totally solved my problem: `q = quote(s.encode('utf8'))`

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and used a helper function to deal with non-ascii and urllib.urlencode function (which includes quote and unquote):

```
def utf8_urlencode(params):
    import urllib as u
    # problem: u.urlencode(params.items()) is not unicode-safe. Must encode all params strings as utf8 first.
    # UTF-8 encodes all the keys and values in params dictionary
    for k,v in params.items():
        # TRY urllib.unquote_plus(artist.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
        if type(v) in (int, long, float):
            params[k] = v
        else:
            try:
                params[k.encode('utf-8')] = v.encode('utf-8')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning( '**ERROR utf8_urlencode ERROR** %s' % e )
    return u.urlencode(params.items()).decode('utf-8')
```

adopted from [Unicode URL encode / decode with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472015/unicode-url-encode-decode-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

So I had the same problem: I wanted to put query parameters in an url, but some of them contained weird characters (diacritics).

Dealing with encoding gave a messy url and was fragile.

My solution was to replace every accent/weird unicode character to its ascii equivalent. It's straightforward thanks to `unidecode`: [What is the best way to remove accents in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string)

```
pip install unidecode
```

then

```
from unidecode import unidecode
print unidecode(u"éèê") 
# prints eee
```

so I have a clean url. Also works for chinese etc.