# Python: How to check if a string is a valid IRI?

Tags: python, url, python-2.7, urlparse

Is there a standard function to check an [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier), to check an URL apparently I can use:

```
parts = urlparse.urlsplit(url)  
    if not parts.scheme or not parts.netloc:  
        '''apparently not an url'''
```

I tried the above with an URL containing Unicode characters:

```
import urlparse
url = "http://fdasdf.fdsfîășîs.fss/ăîăî"
parts = urlparse.urlsplit(url)
if not parts.scheme or not parts.netloc:  
    print "not an url"
else:
    print "yes an url"
```

and what I get is `yes an url`. Does this means I'm good an this tests for valid IRI? Is there another way ?

Comment: Why shouldn't you be good? Does your example violate any rule defined by the IRI standard? In other words: are you asking us if your test breaks any IRI rules? Did you perform this research yourself?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke I am asking someone who has more experience than me with IRI, if I am good with this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using `urlparse` is not sufficient to test for a valid IRI.

Use the [`rfc3987` package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rfc3987) instead:

```
from rfc3987 import parse

parse('http://fdasdf.fdsfîășîs.fss/ăîăî', rule='IRI')
```

Comment: `ImportError: No module named rfc3987` so it is not standard, `pip install rfc3987`

Comment: You have to install the package he links to

Comment: Works (+1), accept, and you are right with:`Using urlparse is not sufficient to test for a valid IRI`, because with the code provided above  `url` string is not a valid IRI, .

Comment: But escaped works: `parse('http://fdasdf.fdsf%C3%AE%C4%83%C8%99%C3%AEs.com/%C4%83%C3%AE%C4%83%C3%AE', rule='IRI')` I get: `{'fragment': None, 'path': '/%C4%83%C3%AE%C4%83%C3%AE', 'scheme': 'http', 'authority': 'fdasdf.fdsf%C3%AE%C4%83%C8%99%C3%AEs.com', 'query': None}`

Comment: Notably, SSH format doesn't comply with URI or IRI: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75668/61349

Comment: I only wish that more people would find this answer when googling.

Answer (score 1):

The only character-set-sensitive code in [the implementation of urlparse](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/urlparse.py) is requiring that the scheme should contain only ASCII letters, digits and [+-.] characters; otherwise it's completely agnostic so will work fine with non-ASCII characters.

As this is [non-documented behaviour](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html), it's your responsibility to check that it continues to be the case (with tests in your project), but I don't imagine it would be changed to break IRIs.

urllib provides [quoting functions](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html?highlight=urllib#utility-functions) to convert IRIs to/from ASCII URIs, although they still don't mention IRIs explicitly in the documentation, and they are broken in some cases: [Is there a unicode-ready substitute I can use for urllib.quote and urllib.unquote in Python 2.6.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557849/is-there-a-unicode-ready-substitute-i-can-use-for-urllib-quote-and-urllib-unquot)

Comment: `urllib.quote(url)` seems to escape the `:` colon in the `http://` to `http%3A//`

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu yes, by default it only works for quoting the path section of an IRI; for a full IRI you'd need to parse, quote, and reassemble the components.