# How to encode unicode to urlenconing in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

How to encode unicode to urlenconing in python 2.7

I want to encode unicode like '€'.

But I don't konw what should I do...

```
>>> u='€'
>>> _u=u'€'
>>> u
'\xa2\xe6'
>>> _u
u'\u20ac'
>>> urllib.quote(u)
'%A2%E6'
>>> urllib.quote(_u)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 1268, in quote
    return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
KeyError: u'\u20ac'
>>> print urllib.unquote(urllib.quote(u))
€
>>>
```

Just I need '%A2%E6' Through unicode '€'.

What should I do?

```
>>> print urllib.unquote(urllib.quote(u'€'.encode('utf8')))
?
```

Comment: encode to utf-8, then everything goes well.       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557849/is-there-a-unicode-ready-substitute-i-can-use-for-urllib-quote-and-urllib-unquot

Comment: Thank you @fanlix, And I read your link. But I still don't know. That link say using encode(). So I tried that. Please see above.

Answer (score 0):

You should `encode` unicode string and then use `urllib.quote`. You yourself wrote the answer to your question

```
urllib.quote(u'€'.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is good. But 'urllib.unquote('%E2%82%AC')' return '%E2%82%AC'. And 'urllib.unquote('%E2%82%AC'')' return '?'

Comment: At my computer script prints correct result: `€`. May be your problem is "bad" stdout encoding? Try run following code `urllib.unquote(urllib.quote(u'€'.encode('utf8'))).decode('utf8')`