# Unicode URL encode / decode with Python

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, unicode

I have an Android app which uses

```
URLEncoder.encode(S.getSongArtist(),"UTF-8")
```

to encode a unicode string that is posted to a AppEngine python (2.7) web service. On the service I use

```
urllib.unquote_plus(artist)
```

This is not giving me correct results. I have an input like this:

```
Marie+Lafor%C3%AAt
```

which is unquote'd to

```
Marie LaforÃªt
```

If I use a javascript url decode, for instance: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/
I get

```
Marie Laforêt
```

A correct result.

I tried using

```
urllib.unquote(artist).decode('utf-8')
```

but this generates an exception. Any hints at all are greatly appreciated.

EDIT

Taxellool had the right answer in the comments:

what you are trying to decode is already decoded. try this:

```
urllib.unquote_plus(artist.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: what exception do you get in last `urllib.unquote(artist).decode('utf-8') `? it seems to work correctly under python2.7.5

Comment: if I use decode at the end i get:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 11-12: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: what you are trying to decode is already decoded.
try this:
`urllib.unquote_plus(artist.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')`

Comment: I tried this in a python shell (as Taxellool did) and it works:
>>> print urllib.unquote_plus(artist).decode('utf-8')
Marie Laforêt
On the server this same line of code generates the exception

Comment: Taxellool - you are right - I tried the unquote(encode).decode and that works - thanks!

Comment: @Taxellool: it should be `urllib.unquote_plus(artist.encode('ascii')).decode('utf-8')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taxellool had the right answer in the comments:

what you are trying to decode is already decoded. try this:

```
urllib.unquote_plus(artist.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are decoding before urllib.unquote():

```
>>> print urllib.unquote_plus('Marie+Lafor%C3%AAt'.decode('utf-8'))  
Marie LaforÃªt
```

If you decode after unquote, result would be what you want:

```
>>> print urllib.unquote_plus('Marie+Lafor%C3%AAt').decode('utf-8')  
Marie Laforêt
```

Just make sure you don't pass a unicode to urllib.unquote_plus.

Comment: On the server this line of code generates an exception: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 11-12: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @scratchy: See [How to print() a string in Python3?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22494825/4279). My answer works on Python 2 too.